# Algoritmo para buscar palindromos por teclado

Tags: javascript

Hola muchachos lo que pasa es que necesito hacer un programa, que le pida al usuario ingresar un número palindromo, una vez el usuario lo ingrese el programa mande un alerta si el número ingresado no es primo, si lo es, entonces que lo convierta en octal y hexadecimal, pero aún no se como hacerlo bien, si alguien me puede ayudar sé lo agradecería.

Llevo esto:

```
function texto() {
    let palabra = prompt("Escribe una palabra").toLowerCase();

    // eliminamos los espacios en blanco
    palabra = palabra.replace(/ /g, "");

    for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
        if (palabra[i] != palabra[palabra.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (texto()) {
    alert("Esto es palíndromo");
} else {
    alert("Esto no es palíndromo")
}
```

Comment: Por favor publicá lo que hayas intentado hacer.

Comment: hola azeós, que pena no coloque el código gracias por la observación

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Lo que veo es un caso de palíndromos, lo que planteas es un número capicúa

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
    Calcula factoriales tanto negativos como positivos
    el factorial de 5 es por ejemplo:

    5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120
*/
function factorial(numero){

    let numeroFactorial = numero;

    //Si es mayor a uno el numero pasado entonces haremos el calculo del factorial
    if(numeroFactorial > 1){

        for(let i = numero - 1; i > 0; i--){

            numeroFactorial *= i;
    
        }

    //Si es mayor o igual a cero pero menor que 1, el factorial de 0 y 1 siempre es 1
    }else if(numeroFactorial >= 0){

        numeroFactorial = 1;

    //Si es menor que 0 pero mayor o igual que -1 entonces el factorial sera -1
    }else if(numeroFactorial < 0 && numeroFactorial > -2){

        numeroFactorial = -1;

    /*
        Si el numero es menor a -1 entonces se hace el calculo con el valor absoluto y
        luego se cambia el signo a negativo.
    */
    }else{

        numeroFactorial = Math.abs(numeroFactorial);
        for(let i = Math.abs(numero) - 1; i > 0; i--){

            numeroFactorial *= i;
    
        }

        numeroFactorial = -numeroFactorial

    }

    return numeroFactorial;

}

/*
    Para calcular si un numero grande es primo debemos sacar primero cuales
    son los primos mas pequeños necesarios para hacer el calculo de si este
    numero grande es primo o no, el limite de estos numeros se calcula desde
    0 hasta la raiz cuadrada aproximada del numero, entonces si por ejemplo
    el numero es 149:

    √149 ≈ 12

    por lo tanto si el numero fuese 149 obtendriamos los numeros primos del
    0 al 12.
*/
function calcularDivisoresPrimos(numero){

    /*
        Calcular la raiz cuadrada de un numero negativo daria resultados inesperados por lo
        tanto la calcularemos sin tener cuenta el signo del numero.
    */
    const raizCuadrada = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(numero)) | 0;
    let primosMinimos = [];

    /*
        Rellenamos el arreglo de primosMinimos de acuerdo a los numeros que se encuentren entre
        0 y el resultado del aproximado de la raiz cuadrada anterior siempre y cuando sean primos.
    */
    for(let i = 0; i <= raizCuadrada; i++){

        /*
            Calculamos si el numero actual de 0 a la raiz cuadrada aproximada es primo
            y lo añadimos al array llamado primosMinimos
        */
        if(i % (factorial(i - 1) + 1) === 0){
            primosMinimos.push(i);
        }

    }

    return primosMinimos;

}

/*
    Detecta si el numero es primo de acuerdo a una lista de otros numeros primos
    mas pequeños que sean necesarios, luego muestra el resultado del numero
    convertido a octal y convertido a hexadecimal.
*/
function esPrimo(numeroString){

    //Convertimos el string a un entero, si no la función calcularDivisoresPrimosDariaProblema.
    const numero = parseInt(numeroString);
    const primerosPrimos = calcularDivisoresPrimos(numero);
    let isPrime = false;

    //Si hay divisores primos hacemos el cálculo de acuerdo a todos ellos
    if(primerosPrimos.length > 0){

        for(let i = 0; i < primerosPrimos.length; i++){

            if((numero % primerosPrimos[i] < primerosPrimos[i]) && !(numero % primerosPrimos[i] === 0)){
    
                isPrime = !isPrime;
                break;
    
            }else if(numero % primerosPrimos[i] === 0){
    
                break;
                
            }
    
        }

    }else{

        /*
            Nota: si se llega aquí es porque el numero es si o si <= 4 o >= -4

            Si no hay divisores primos hacemos el cálculo de acuerdo a la formula
            de wilson:

            Un número n es primo si y solo si (n-1)! + 1 es múltiplo de n

            NOTA: NUNCA USAR ESTA FORMULA PARA NUMEROS MAYORES A 9 esto afectaria mucho el
            rendimiento y provocaria errores, usarla solo para numeros no mayores a 9.
        */
        isPrime = Math.abs(numero) % (factorial(Math.abs(numero) - 1) + 1) === 0 ? true : false;

    }

    alert(isPrime ? `El numero: ${numero} es primo` : `El numero: ${numero} no es primo`);

    /*
        A la función toString se le puede pasar un parametro según la documentación oficial de esta
        esta recibe como parametro la base a convertir del string, entonces algunos posibles formatos
        serían:

        binario: base 2
        octal: base 8
        hexadecimal: base 16

        notese que se le pasa para octal el numero 8, y para hexadecimal el numero 16
    */
    alert("Numero en octal: " + numero.toString(8));
    alert("Numero en hexadecimal: " + numero.toString(16));
    return isPrime;

}

/*
    Se encarga de decirnos si el valor de nuestro input tipo numero es palindromo o no
    y luego ejecuta la función es primo.
*/
function esPalindromo()
{
    //Obtenemos el valor del input tipo numero
    let palabra = document.getElementById("inputNumeros").value;
    let esPalindroma = true;
    //Convertimos el numero obtenido a string
    palabra = palabra.toString();
    /*
        Creo que esta parte no es necesaria, pero no estoy seguro 
        así que mejor colocarlo, esto sirve para eliminar espacios en blanco
    */
    palabra = palabra.trim();
    let antiIndex = 0;

    for (let i = palabra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

        if(palabra[i] != palabra[antiIndex]){
            esPalindroma = !esPalindroma;
            break;
        }

        antiIndex++;
    }
    
    alert(esPalindroma ? "Esto es palíndromo" : "Esto no es palíndromo");
    esPrimo(palabra);
    return esPalindroma;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Funciones matematicas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "number" placeholder = "Digita un numero" value = "0" id = "inputNumeros"/>
    <input type="button" value="Comprobar!" onclick="esPalindromo()">
</body>
</html>
```

Para crear este código me he basado en las siguientes referencias:

[¿Cómo saber si un numero es primo o no?](https://www.wikiprimes.com/como-saber-si-un-numero-es-primo/)

[Factorial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

[Averiguar si un numero es primo](https://matematicasies.com/Averiguar-si-un-numero-es-primo)

La explicación del código esta en el mismo código, sin embargo talvez no entiendas algunas cosas... así que hare unas explicaciones mas:

```
i % (factorial(i - 1) + 1) === 0
```

Es la formula para calcular un numero primo, donde el operador % llamado tambien modulo o residuo **no es la operación porcentaje**, esta operación es el resultado de el residuo que queda de dividir un numero entre otro, por ejemplo:

```
4 % 2 = 0;
```

Es cero debido a que su division es exacta, mientras que:

```
4 % 3 = 1;
```

Es uno debido a que 4 / 3 = aprox 1

Otra cosa que probablemente deba explicar es esto de aquí:

```
Math.sqrt(Math.abs(numero)) | 0
```

Lo que probablemente veas raro es ese `| 0` , resumidamente es una forma de hacer esto mismo:

```
Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(numero)));
```

Donde el operador `|` seguido del numero cero transforma cualquier numero que haya antes de `|` a un entero:

```js
console.log(285.647 | 0);
```

Comment: Bro, agradezco la buena voluntad que tienes para dar con la solución, un detalle importante: Si los nuevos programadores muestran CERO intento de solución y solo quieren que les hagan las tareas y la comunidad las hace, seguirán habiendo más preguntas así. Generalmente se las responde cuando se percibe que el usuario ha intentado hacer algo por su cuenta :)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón compañero @fredyfx , efectivamente, pues... ya cree el código, pero si, lo tendre en cuenta para futuras respuestas, ojala mi respuesta sirva de ayuda para el mejor entendimiento de los problemas.

Comment: Vale, gracias por la comprensión y la colaboración :)